# Order mysql results vs like

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `tele`.`pedidos` 
          WHERE  `data` LIKE '".date('d/m/Y')."';";
```

How can I order this by any column? I try:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `tele`.`pedidos` 
          WHERE  `data` LIKE '".date('d/m/Y')." 
          ORDER BY numero DESC';";
```

But doesnt work...

Any suggestion?

Comment: Like is a [string comparation function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like). This means that a type cating are made for each table row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you are getting syntax error exception right? It's because you lack single quote after the value of date. Try this for clearer view,

```
$dateHere = date('d/m/Y');
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `tele`.`pedidos` WHERE  `data` LIKE '$dateHere' ORDER BY numero DESC';";
```

if you are searching for a specific date, use `=` not `LIKE` because it's for pattern matching

```
$dateHere = date('d/m/Y');
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `tele`.`pedidos` WHERE  `data` = '$dateHere' ORDER BY numero DESC';";
```

Comment: Correct and explicative. Thanks

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that's why the statement says: **if** the value(s) came from the outside.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson so what do you call this? `date('d/m/Y')`. anyway, i'll just remove it so more **nonsense** words on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The single quote in the second query is misplaced.  The failure to work could possibly be related to that.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `tele`.`pedidos` WHERE  `data` LIKE '".date('d/m/Y')."' ORDER BY numero DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

The query syntax is basically right but the single quotes are wrong:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `tele`.`pedidos` WHERE  `data` = '".date('d/m/Y')."' ORDER BY numero DESC;";
```

Actually, this query doesn't make sense.  Originally, I read the question that the first query worked but not the second (hence the focus on quotes).  Are you trying to say that the date is today?  What is data?  A string data type or a date data type?

If you wanted to find a match to today and data is a character string, it would be more like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `tele`.`pedidos`
          WHERE date( `data`) = date(now())
          ORDER BY numero DESC;";
```

Comment: Please, change like by `=`. Like is for string comparation. Sure you now, you should include this information in your answer.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like